# Update Tax rate base on store pickup

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, shipping-address

I am working on Magento 2. Currently I configured the tax calculate based on shipping address. We have option for store pickup also.

So the issue is that when user enter the shipping address, tax is calculating , but after that if user select the shipping method to "Store Pickup" then tax should calculate based on store address. We have one store address.

If user don't select store pickup then tax should calculate based on shipping address. If store pickup is selected then tax should calculate based on store address.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this scenario?